# How to make administration menu display child links without child url

Tags: routes, navigation, path-aliases

My question is probably a little confusing, so I'm gonna explain with an example. Whenever I create a parent link like "admin/test/execute", the administration menu will display the link and if I create another link "admin/test/execute/log" the menu will display "log" as a child of "execute". 
My problem is when I try to add a child to "admin/test/execute" with the following link "admin/structure/ctools-content/list/page", the administration menu doesn't display this link. I tried creating an url alias("admin/test/execute/page") but when I add the alias to the menu, the alias get's converted to the original url.

**Solution:**

The solution to my problem was in the menu item weight instead of using the drag and drop option, I've changed the parent link weight, and the links started getting displayed correctly.